# Ionic 2 Modal multiple get data

Tags: ionic-framework, get, modal-dialog, ionic2

sorry for my english, I try to get multiple data from a modal but this not work.

This is the code in modal.ts:

```
anadir() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.cantidad, this.idpedido, this.posicion);
  }
```

and this is the code in page.ts:

```
 myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    this.idpedido = data.idpedido;
    this.cantidad = data.cantidad;
    this.posicion = data.posicion;
    console.log(data)

    });
```

The data that i get is "undefined", thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending three different properties, you can try by sending a single object with three properties like this:

```
anadir() {
   this.viewCtrl.dismiss({ 
       idpedido: this.idpedido, 
       cantidad: this.cantidad,
       posicion: this.posicion
   });
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)